# DropBox core dump error and force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment

Tags: 14.10, sync, dropbox

I am running Ubuntu 14.10, and I was just syncing one of my folders with my DropBox cloud storage space using this command in Terminal:

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

But when it was done (although it could have been during the upload because I was not monitoring it and only noticed after I had quite DropBox) I noticed this error output:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Also, when I clicked the option "Launch DropBox Website" I got this output even though it did successfully manage to launch the DropBox website and log me in:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment
```

I have checked my files which it was uploading during the process of the syncing and they seem fine and intact, so what do these errors mean? And what could the cause and effects of them be? And are they connected?

Comment: File a bug report with Dropbox. It's probably not a big deal if Dropbox continues to function.

Comment: @muru: How do I file a bug report to them? Where do I go to file the report?

Comment: Here, I suppose: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/topics/200203389-Bugs-Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

I've found that few people were able to solve:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment
```

Through the use of this method, but it is worth a try.